# Error trying to access members of Array of AnyObject within a Dictionary - Is there a way around unwrapping?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary set up as:

```
var jDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject[]>()
```

Where the arrays are either a collection of custom buttons (JunkButton) or Labels (JunkLabels).

I am having an issue when trying to access the members of the arrays contained in the Dictionary as follows:

```
let thisArray = jDict[key]
var aButton = thisArray[0]  //Gives error: 'AnyObject[]? does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

I can get around this by downcasting the whole array as follows:

```
if let aArray = thisArray as? JunkButton[]{
    var aButton = aArray[0]
}
```

This seems very cumbersome especially if I am sure I know what type the array is made up of beforehand.  Is there a way to cast thisArray when it is created that would allow me to extract its elements without unwrapping them each time?

Comment: It is not the elements of `thisArray` that are wrapped. It is `thisArray` _itself_ that is wrapped. `AnyObject[]?` means "an Optional containing an Array of AnyObject".

Comment: You can just leave out the downcast (`as? JunkButton[]`) and it will still work. But `aButton` will be of type `AnyObject?` then which is probably not what you want. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dictionary` always give you `Optional` value.

Your code is like this

```
let thisArray : Optional<AnyObject[]> = jDict[key]
```

You need to unwrap it to get non-optional value

```
let thisArray = jDict[key]! // thisArray is AnyObject[]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did this and now I can access the array element with:  var aButton = thisArray[0] as JunkButton.  Worked like a charm.  I am still getting my head around Optionals but I think it is starting to click.

Comment: I don't think use of the force-unwrap operator should be encouraged. It defeats the type system and can cause runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use a dictionary for this. Swift makes it very easy to use custom little structs or classes instead of dictionaries:

```
struct JunkItems {
  var buttons: [JunkButton] = []
  var labels: [JunkLabel] = []
}
```

Then you can access those items like this without downcasting:

```
for button in junkItems.buttons {
  // ...
}
```

Or:

```
if let button = junkItems.buttons[0] {
  // ...
}
```

Btw, the array notation [JunkButton] is new in beta 3.

Comment: the Swift way is `enum JunkItem { case Button(JunkButton), case Label(JunkLabel) }`